# Downgrade Pycharm Professional to Community

Tags: pycharm

I have installed pycharm professional trail version on my Ubuntu now the trail version is expired and now i want to know if there is any way downgrading it to pycharm community without uninstalling the pycharm?

Comment: How did you install PyCharm Professional Edition?

Comment: Same question here. My guess was: 
1. export settings from Pycharm Pro, 
2. download Pycharm CE, 
3. import settings into Pycharm CE.
However, the import wizard throws:
"/path/settings.jar does not appear to be PyCharm Community Edition config folder or installation home".

I am still stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a direct solution either, but an Export of settings from Professional and Import settings in Community works. And it's fast and easy.

1. In Professional Edition go to File/Manage IDE Settings/Export Settings

[image]

2. In Community Edition go to File/Manage IDE Settings/Import Settings and import the ZIP file.

[image]

3. Grab a beer and start coding.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the Pro license has expired, preventing you from running it?

Comment: @davidA I was able to activate the trial when my subscription ended just to pull the settings. Also, I think it can pull the settings from the pro version if you haven't uninstalled it yet. The community edition will prompt on install and point to the pro version directory. Didn't try it myself though