# How does one downgrade pycharm version -- ideally without uninstalling pycharm or keeping multiple version?

Tags: pycharm

I'm currently facing an issue with the latest version of pycharm (detailed at the end). Due to that I want to downgrade pycharm version from 2023.4 to 2023.2 or 2023.3 such that it disturbs my computer the least e.g., not losing settings, projects, deployment configs, avoiding keeping multiple version of the idea in my computer to avoid confusions, etc.

How does one do this? I couldn't find anything on their website or the settings menu or google.

---

Concrete context:

```
I'm trying to push to my servers on save and manually. It doesn't work. I updated to version:
PyCharm 2023.1.4 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-231.9225.15, built on July 11, 2023
Licensed to [Me]
Subscription is active until January 13, 2024.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 17.0.7+10-b829.16 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.2.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.intellij.ideolog (222.1.0.0)
nl.rubensten.texifyidea (0.7.32)
IdeaVIM (2.4.0)
com.github.copilot (1.2.15.2816)
reasonml (0.114-2023.1)
com.leinardi.pycharm.pylint (0.15.0)

it doesn't work. If I go directly to the SSH configuration by clicking the ... button next to the me@uni.edu then try to connect from there using Test Connection it connects. But one window before the ... the Test Connection doesn't work. Push on save doesn't work. Also, manually pushing doesn't work. There is a fatal bug that wasted a lot of time for me today. Needs to be urgently fixed.
```

related:

- [Downgrade pycharm from 2019.1 to 2018.2 but keep settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475627/downgrade-pycharm-from-2019-1-to-2018-2-but-keep-settings)
- [Downgrade Pycharm Professional to Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720950/downgrade-pycharm-professional-to-community)

cross: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12595084799762-How-does-one-downgrade-pycharm-version-ideally-without-uninstalling-pycharm-or-keeping-multiple-version-

Comment: With JetBrain toolbox, you can upgrade and downgrade easily, but I'm not sure if it can downgrade only previously installed version and/or only version installed with toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended to use Toolbox in order to manage your IDEs. You can easily install/uninstall/update and install different versions with it. In regards to your configuration whenever you remove an IDE your settings and projects are not deleted and you can easily import them once you reinstall it- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings

Alternatively the list to download different versions manually is here - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/other.html

In regards to your original issue, please [submit a report](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731&product=PyCharm&build=231.9225.15&os=mac&timezone=Europe/Amsterdam) with Support in order to get additional details about the matter.